# Unable to load torrent file using raw base64 form and python xmlrpc client

Tags: python, python-3.x, torrent

I am trying to load a torrent file into rtorrent using xmlrpc with the following python3 code:

```
import xmlrpc.client

server_url = "https://%s:%s@%s/xmlrpc" % ('[REDACTED]', '[REDACTED]', '[REDACTED]');
server = xmlrpc.client.Server(server_url);

with open("test.torrent", "rb") as torrent:
    server.load.raw_verbose(xmlrpc.client.Binary(torrent.read()),"d.delete_tied=","d.custom1.set=Test","d.directory.set=/home/[REDACTED]/files")
```

The `load_raw` command returns without an error (return code 0), but the torrent does not appear in the rutorrent UI. I seem to be experiencing the same thing as from [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/torrents/comments/78dy1i/programatically_getting_torrents_out_of_deluge_or/) reddit post, but I am using the `Binary` class without any luck.

I am using a [Whatbox](https://whatbox.ca/) seedbox.

EDIT:

After enabling logging I am seeing

```
1572765194 E Could not create download, the input is not a valid torrent.
```

when trying to load the torrent file, however manually loading the torrent file through the rutorrent UI works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add `""` as the first argument:

```
server.load.raw_verbose("",xmlrpc.client.Binary(torrent.read()),"d.delete_tied=","d.custom1.set=Test","d.directory.set=/home/[REDACTED]/files")
```

Not sure why, the [docs](https://rtorrent-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmd-ref.html#term-load-raw-verbose) don't seem to show this is needed.